# Picker Angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular8

Estoy utilizando angular 8, cuando escojo una fecha y doy aceptar en vez de enviar la fecha seleccionada envía la fecha actual, en todos los casos siempre toma la fecha actual y no la seleccionada.
En el **HTML** tengo lo siguiente:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Año de Publicación" 
    [max]="maxFecha" formControlName="fecha">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

En el archivo `.ts` tengo lo siguiente:

```
maxFecha: Date = new Date();

ngOnInit() {
this.form = new FormGroup({
'fecha': new FormControl(new Date()),
});
```

Para enviar la fecha tengo lo siguiente:

```
operar() {
let book = new Book();
var tzoffset = (this.form.value['fecha']).getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
var localISOTime = (new Date(Date.now() - tzoffset)).toISOString()
book.fecha = localISOTime;
console.log(book.fecha)
}
```

A pesar de que se elija la fecha del día anterior o cualquier fecha cuando realiza `operar()` envía la fecha actual, cual sería el error?

Comment: Debes agregar el formGroup en el contenedor del formulario en tu HTML: `[formGroup]="form"`

Answer (score 1):

En tu html, en el contenedor de tu formulario, debes incluir `[formGroup]="form"` para que Angular sepa de qué grupo son los campos:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    ...
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Año de Publicación" 
        [max]="maxFecha" formControlName="fecha">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Si lo tengo de esa manera:

<form class="example-container" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="operar()" #frmBook="ngForm">
.
.
.
</form>

Los otros campos que tengo en el formulario se crean y editan bien pero con el picker no funciona solo envía la fecha actual